# describe giving wrong format numbers

Tags: pandas, format, describe

I have created a new calculated numeric column to my df. When I run describe function on this new column, I get all numbers with decimal placed in wrong place. For example, I get count as 2.04, when I know that df has 204 rows. When I run describe on the whole df, for all other variables I get count as 204, while for this one I get as 2.04. Is this because I dont have my variable in correct format? dtypes tells me it is a float64 type, which is what I expected. Could someone please help me understand and fix this?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Because I was multiplying with a small number, the describe gave display as count 2.040000e+02, and I believe that means I need to shift decimal to right by two numbers. I am posting so that maybe it will help someone else

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).